# for each loop with specific key value in multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've been using the following to build a clause for multiple deletes at once which works great.  This was for single dimension arrays though.

```
$prefix = $in_clause = '';
$binding_clause = array();  
foreach($selected as $key => $value)
{
    $in_clause .= $prefix.':selected_'.$key;
    $prefix = ', ';
    $binding_clause[':selected_'.$key] = $value;
}
```

Now, I need to use it on a specific value of a multidimensional array.  Given this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [account_id] => 2
            [screenshot_id] => 120262
            [image_filename] => a1.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [account_id] => 2
            [screenshot_id] => 120263
            [image_filename] => a2.jpg
        )
    .......
```

I only need the key value and the screenshot_id value so I am trying to change the first function so the values are :

```
key = 0, value = 120262
key = 1, value = 120263
```

Hopefully that makes sense.  Not sure how to do this with a multi-array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the array elements are arrays, use array indexing to access that part of the elements:

```
foreach ($selected as $key => $value) {
    $binding_clause[':selected_'.$key] = $value['screenshot_id'];
}
```

Comment: That's it.  Guess I was overthinking it there as I didn't think value would take the array.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the `array` format as explained above.

```
for($i=0; $i<=$array.count(); $i++){
    foreach($array[$i] as $key => $value){
        echo "Key: ". $i . " Value:" . $key['screenshot_id']
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the nested loop.